Visual Studio Errors bugging out
Visual Studio 2022 is bugging out when it comes to errors.
The error squiggles are no longer showing under ANY of the errors.
Also, when I click an error item in the Error list, it no longer takes me directly to the error.
I have tried going into Tools > Options > Text-Editor > General > Show Error squiggles, that box is already checked and still no error squiggles are showing.
I have tried running the Repair option from the Visual Studio installer.
I have completely uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio.
I have tried deleting all of the hidden .vs folders.
Nothing seems to bring back my error squiggles and nothing is bringing back the functionality where you click on an error in the error list and you are taken to the error.

For the problem that the error prompt underline disappears and the error list click is invalid when you use Visual Studio 2022, you can try the following suggestions:
1: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings.
2: If you have any extensions installed, such as Resharper or others, try to temporarily disable them, as they will interfere with the display of error wavy lines.

I gave this a shot and still no error squiggles. Thank you though.

Please try to restore the default settings by typing devenv /ResetSettings in the Developer Command Prompt for VS. Or try to create a new project and check if the problem persists.
